# Measurable Function on Product Space

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory

Letting $f:[0,1]\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be measurable, and letting $F(x,y) = f(x)-f(y)$, is $F$ necessarily measurable?

Answer (score 0):

$F_1(x,y)=f(x)$ and $F_2(x,y)=f(y)$ are measurable (Can you verify this?). Hence $F=F_1-F_2$ is measurable.